# 英語が残っている: 回答のついた質問を削除する時のダイアログ: cancel

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: cancel]

Answer (score 1):

> キャンセル

Comment: 翻訳は入っていますが、コードは日本語を使っていなかったらしいです。開発者へ通知しましたので、しばらくお待ちください。